# Headless Chrome driver not returning required results

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
def get_country(product_number):

    options = Options();
    options.add_argument("--headless")

    chrome_driver_path = "D://Softwares//ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path,chrome_options=options);
    driver.get("www.example.com")
    srch = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Search millions of products and datasheets']")
    srch.send_keys(product_number)
    btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='Embedded-search-button']")
    btn.click()
    tit = []
    man = []
    des = []
    try:
        parent=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("dl.BuyingOptions-labeledValues")
        country=parent.find_element_by_xpath("//dt[contains(.,'Country Of Origin')]/following::dd[1]")
        co = country.text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        co = ""

    pare = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WideSidebarProductList-item-details']")
    if (len(pare)!=0):
        for par in pare:
            title = par.find_element_by_xpath("./h4[@class='WideSidebarProductList-item-title']")
            manu = par.find_element_by_xpath("./h5[@class='WideSidebarProductList-item-manufacturer']")
            desc = par.find_element_by_xpath("./p[@class='WideSidebarProductList-item-description']")
            tit.append(title.text)
            man.append(manu.text)
            des.append(desc.text)

    print("Done")
    return co,tit,man,des
```

Now when I do not use the chrome options then the code works fine but when I use the headless option the chrome returns empty lists for `tit`, `man` and `des`. The log is as follows:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51306/devtools/browser/4b0749ed-d971-44f4-9a29-8e0975f24432
[0801/152120.248:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Download the Apollo DevTools for a better development experience: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm", source: https://static4.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/vendor.31e3ee1d4101f4c0fe7f.js (1)
[0801/152122.459:INFO:CONSOLE(5)] "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://cdn.krxd.net') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://www.arrow.com').", source: https://cdn.krxd.net/ctjs/controltag.js.05f9d0dad02f8a1b0b028b868bc3a3e2 (5)
[0801/152130.672:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "global-jssState", source: https://www.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/11.45371a769e02a2e956ed.js (1)
[0801/152130.674:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "pdp-wrapper-this", source: https://www.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/11.45371a769e02a2e956ed.js (1)
[0801/152140.790:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Download the Apollo DevTools for a better development experience: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apollo-client-developer-t/jdkknkkbebbapilgoeccciglkfbmbnfm", source: https://static4.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/vendor.31e3ee1d4101f4c0fe7f.js (1)
[0801/152141.400:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "global-jssState", source: https://www.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/11.45371a769e02a2e956ed.js (1)
[0801/152141.402:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "pdp-wrapper-this", source: https://www.arrow.com/dist/arrow/browser/11.45371a769e02a2e956ed.js (1)
Done
 ['', '', '', ''] ['', '', '', ''] ['', '', '', '']
```

Do I need the apollo client developer as suggested by log or is there a way around this?

Comment: The reason could be the browser have not loaded the content in headless mode, but the code executes earlier. So, you find nothing. You could run the code under a faster network or add some wait argument in your code. Or make a while loop to find the element until succeed.

Comment: The number of elements that it finds inside the loop is fine which is four so it shows four empty texts in the list which means it is able to get the correct number of elements. Its just that the text is empty. Also the first perimeter `co` is returning fine which is also on the same page. The page is not changing in any way inside the loop then how can it not locate `h4`, `h5` and `p` tags. Inside the loop. Also if the `title`, `manu` and `desc` elements were not found then there should have been a `NoSuchElementException` as I am not checking for that

Comment: Well, try to print pare and see what you have got.

Comment: Yes I have, printing pare shows the 4 webdriver elements and printing par inside loop shows the individual elements(along with session and stuff) something like this `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="8f6e788492c4715c6a72bb7c16a8d7e2", element="8caee60f-9a52-49d6-adb7-68fe98c41b06")>` but even printing par.text shows empty string on each iteration.

Comment: can you paste the website,I will check the problem.

Comment: https://www.arrow.com/en/products/lmk107bbj475mklt/taiyo-yuden
Here is the link if that can help

Comment: First I go to this link then add product number in search bar and press search button. From the resulting page I get the elements

Comment: I have checked, the headless web driver is definitely banned by the website. But you could save the `page_source` and use `beautifulsoup` to extract what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
You can try using WebDriverWait in combination with lambda where in you specify to find the element with text otherwise the webpage may be loaded but not the elements text.

A example would be:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# 10 stands for time to definitely wait, it will look every 500 milliseconds if element returns successful 
btn =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('/your/xpath'))
btn.click()
title =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_xpath('/your/xpath').text)
tit.append(title)
return tit
```